# Labeling the Indices of a Data-frame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am trying to label the indices of a data-frame. Now, under normal circumstances, it should be like this:

```
pd.DataFrame(fruits, columns=['Name of Fruit', 'Price'], 
                     index=['Aug. 01, 2017', 'Aug. 02, 2018'])
```

Now these indices are labelled for just two days of a month. For example, if i have to index them for whole month or for whole year using notations like A1 for August 1, A2 for August 2 ... so, what would be the ideal way of doing this?

I am trying to be less labor-intensive by not putting every date manually.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
index = pd.Series(pd.date_range(start='20170101', periods=99, freq='D')
                    .strftime('%b.%d')) \
          .str.replace(r'(.).*?(\d+)', r'\1\2')
```

yields:

```
In [74]: index
Out[74]:
0     J01
1     J02
2     J03
3     J04
4     J05
5     J06
6     J07
7     J08
8     J09
9     J10
     ...
89    M31
90    A01
91    A02
92    A03
93    A04
94    A05
95    A06
96    A07
97    A08
98    A09
Length: 99, dtype: object
```

**Explanation:**

```
In [5]: pd.date_range(start='20170725', periods=10, freq='D').strftime('%b.%d')
Out[5]:
array(['Jul.25', 'Jul.26', 'Jul.27', 'Jul.28', 'Jul.29', 'Jul.30', 'Jul.31', 'Aug.01', 'Aug.02', 'Aug.03'],
      dtype='<U6')
```

then we can replace those strings so that we will keep only first letters and numbers (day) at the end...

Comment: Thanks MaxU ... could you please explain as to what happens by these two, i.e., .strftime('%b.%d')).str.replace(r'(.).*?(\d+)', r'\1\2'). Also, i can see that the alphabets are changing from J to M to A ... is there a way to keep these alphabets as static?

Comment: Is there any other way to generate an index like A1, A2, A3, A4,....An ... without using these datarange functions?

Comment: @John, what's wrong with using those date_range functions?

Comment: I intend to keep variable as static and not dynamic in index.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`date_range`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.date_range.html) function.

```
# One year, daily
pd.date_range(start='20170801', end='20180731', freq='D') 

# Starting from August 1, 2017 - 365 days
pd.date_range(start='20170801', periods=365, freq='D') 

# Ending at July 31, 2018 - 365 days
pd.date_range(end='20180731', periods=365, freq='D')
```

These should replace the list you are passing as index. For example, `pd.DataFrame(index=pd.date_range(start='20170801', end='20180731', freq='D'))`.

Comment: Thank you. But i am actually interested not in passing numbers as 20180731 but rather something with alphabets too.